# How to achive Cassandra O'Reilly Architect Certification

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

About the Architect Certification aviable for version 2.x at O'Reilly, in what manner the questions on this certification varies from the other two available (Administrator and Developer) Do you suggest some additional material to study for this specific certification?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do the certification but as you can see [here](https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=certInfo&branding=OREILLY&tabs=13) the developer course is only focussing on data modeling and core concepts, where for the others Ops and Performance tuning comes in.

But do you think that these certifications do have any value? This is a general question.

Last but not least, I don't think that there is any difference between the versions since they're referring to the datastax courses.

Best